# Calling the same cell of different worksheets in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a drop down list (with name of sheets) and based on that value, let's say that I select the Sheet4 as in the image, I want to bring to another sheet the value of that selection, let's say on the cell B8.

[image]

I know that this works:

```
=IF(B1="Sheet1", Sheet1!B8, IF(B1="Sheet2", Sheet2!B8, Sheet3!B8))
```

That's for just 3 sheets but is there a nicer or more efficient way to do this?

This is in general how all the sheets look like:

[image]

Comment: **** after the selection of B1, sorry.

Comment: Use INDIRECT to construct a valid worksheet and cell reference from text-that-looks-like-a-worksheet-and-cell-reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use INDIRECT to construct a valid worksheet and cell reference from text-that-looks-like-a-worksheet-and-cell-reference <sup>1</sup>

The indirect takes a string and turns it into a valid reference.

```
=INDIRECT("'" & B1 & "'!B8")
```

So in the case above it would create a string `"'Sheet4!B8"`.  Then the Indirect will turn it into a valid cell reference.

As Jeeped also pointed out in the comments The B8 reference since it is literal text it will not change if the formula is copied or dragged to another cell.

The B1 which is a cell reference and is relative will change as it is copied or dragged to different cells.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> as per @Jeeped comment</sub>

Comment: Bonus for realizing that `B8` did not have to be `$B$8` (string literals never change).